# Own timeout message after ftp.connect in python

Tags: python, ftp, timeout, ftplib

I am writing a script moving files from FTP server (a smartphone) to local, current directory.
My code is as follows:

```
ftp = FTP()
ftp.connect(host='192.168.0.24', port=2121, timeout=5)
ftp.login()
ftp.cwd('MIUI/sound_recorder/call_rec')
for filename in ftp.nlst(): # get filenames within the directory:
    if filename not in ['.', '..']:
        with open(filename.encode('latin-1').decode(), 'wb') as f_output:
            ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, f_output.write)
        ftp.delete(filename)
ftp.quit()
```

I set 5 seconds time out in `ftp.connect`.  After the timeout, the script is terminated. Instead, I would like to display a message saying that the server should be turned on and the connection attempted again. How to do it?

Comment: `display a message saying that the server should be turned on and the connection attempted again.` To achieve this you would ideally need another function that is overlooking the `ftp` process. Look into the observer design pattern or even multiprocessing in python

Comment: Thank you for an interesting suggestion of direction. About _observer design pattern_, I have found page [Refactoring](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/observer/python/example). How to implement the pattern here?

Answer (score 0):

The successful script is below.

```
ftp = FTP()
timeout = 5
ntrials = 12
connected = False
while ntrials > 0: 
    try:
        ftp.connect(host='192.168.0.24', port=2121, timeout=timeout)
    except:
        print("Switch the server on.", timeout * ntrials, "seconds left.")
        ntrials -= 1
    else:
        ntrials = 0
        connected = True
if connected:
    ftp.login()
    ftp.cwd('MIUI/sound_recorder/call_rec')
    for filename in ftp.nlst(): # get filenames within the directory:
        if filename not in ['.', '..']:
            with open(filename.encode('latin-1').decode(), 'wb') as f_output:
                ftp.retrbinary('RETR '+ filename, f_output.write)
            ftp.delete(filename)
    ftp.quit()
    print("The transfer is done")
else:
    print("No connection")
```